# Linked Image disappears on hover in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, hyperlink, cross-browser, wordpress

This question is kind of related to WordPress in that the bug is with the 'forum toolset' in Simple:Press. However I have asked a question on the WordPress stack  exchange website and it hasn't drawn any attention, which I think is because the question would be more suited to here...

The situation is as follows. In Simple:Press, when you have been granted the correct permissions, hovering over a topic icon will make a toolbox icon appear in the top left hand corner of the topic icon. When clicked, this toolbox icon will display a popup dialog containing options to manage the topic - however, in IE9 it is impossible to click the toolbox icon; a very frustrating problem occurs which does **not** occur in Firefox... Whenever my cursor goes over the toolbox icon it disappears before I have chance to click on it!

Unfortunately, I can only test it on Internet Explorer and Firefox, but I can definately say that the problem doesn't occur in  Firefox. Here is the code that does the  job:

```
<div class='spForumTopicSection spOdd' id='topic52'>
<a class='spToolsButton vtip' id='spForumToolButton52' title='Open the forum toolset' rel='nofollow' href='javascript:void(null)'  style='display:none;'  onclick='spjDialogAjax(this, "http://diabetesuknelfsg.org.uk/index.php?sp_ahah=admintoollinks&amp;sfnonce=0aaa9b0764&amp;action=topictools&amp;topic=52&amp;forum=4&amp;page=1", "Forum Tools", 250, 0, 0);' ><img class='spIcon' src='http://diabetesuknelfsg.org.uk/wp-content/sp-resources/forum-themes/default/images/sp_ForumTools.png' alt=''/></a>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        var sptb = {
            class   : '.spForumTopicSection'
        };
        /* ]]> */
        </script>
        <div class='spColumnSection spLeft' style='width: 6%; min-height: 50px;'>
<img id='spTopicIndexIcon52' class='spRowIcon spLeft' src='http://diabetesuknelfsg.org.uk/wp-content/sp-resources/forum-themes/default/images/sp_TopicIcon.png' alt='' />
</div>
```

Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Dear andy can you show this problem in real time so i can catch you problem ASAP.

Comment: Happy Singh, how do you mean in real time? The problem is that I can't really give anyone permissions so that they can experience this for themselves - especially not if they live outside of the UK!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not exactly the solution I had hoped for but is all I could do, especially seeing as though the website is live ... I've just forced the tool box icon to stay visible all of time.

I was able to do this because I found that the forum theme was calling a function (in a file that was really hard to find [`/simple-press/forum/content/sp-forum-view-functions.php`] as there was no indication as to which file was being called).

I simply removed the line that set `style="display:none"` and also the Javascript. It still comes up differently in different browsers but it always works now, which is good enough for me.

It's a shame Simple:Press don't offer the forum for their *free plugin* free of charge as well!...